# Flexbox elements scrolling over navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm slowly getting into CSS and HTML and so far I've been making a page where there's a navbar on top and a list of elements below it. The elements in said list change their shape, too, but this is not the purpose of my question. 
The issue I'm having is that while scrolling, the container class elements just scroll on top of the navbar, making it kinda pointless.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 700px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.container div.containerinfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0.75;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Navbar</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="broken" alt="broken link">
      <div class="containerinfo">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src="broken" alt="broken link">
      <div class="containerinfo">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src="broken" alt="broken link">
      <div class="containerinfo">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src="broken" alt="broken link">
      <div class="containerinfo">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src="broken" alt="broken link">
      <div class="containerinfo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckuuxqqr/6/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `header` comes first in the source code, the yellow `div` elements will layer above it on the z-axis.

Here are two options to make header appear on top:

1. Add `z-index: 1` to `header`. This will move the `header` to the top of other elements without a higher `z-index` value. (The default value for all elements is `auto`.)  [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckuuxqqr/7/)
2. Put the `header` element last in the source code. [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckuuxqqr/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add z-index:1; to your header css.  z index will determine the "stacking" of elements on the page.  The higher the index the higher it will stack on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Add the z-index and here's why-->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index